# Win 10 - How to bootstrap CMD/Powershell/WSL (CLI) juxtaposed in the right corner of the screen?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, putty

Each time I start CLI program like `CMD`/`Powershell`/`C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`, it starts very much on the left of the screen (image 1) and I need to drag them into the right corner of the screen so they would be juxtaposed to it, and fill up half of the screen (image 2):

[image]

---

[image]

Each time anew, I need to drag the window so it would appear nicely juxtaposed to the right, as in the above image... What can be done to have this behavior automatically ?

---

Update for David Postill:

David, I moved the screen as needed (as you can see) but it is still situated in the default place.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What can be done to have this behavior automatically?

1. Right click the title bar and select "Defaults".

   [image]
2. Select the "Layout" tab.
3. Uncheck "Let system position window"

   [image]
4. Set "Windows Size" fields "Width" and "Height" as appropriate
5. Set "Window Position" fields "Left" and "Top" as appropriate
6. Click "OK"