# PuTTY - How to automatically snap window to the right?

Tags: windows-10, putty, aero-snap

I use PuTTY to (SSH) tunnel into my VPS. It's a bit annoying to me to manually juxtapose its window to the right edge of the screen **automatically**?

How could I lock it to start in the right edge of the screen?

See images **before** manual snapping and after snapping (what I need to do each time I open PuTTY):

[[image: unpinned]]

[[image: pinned]]

### Update for Martin Prikryl:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win 10 - How to bootstrap CMD/Powershell/Putty (CLI) juxtaposed in the right corner of the screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/1162190/win-10-how-to-bootstrap-cmd-powershell-putty-cli-juxtaposed-in-the-right-cor)

Comment: No, it's not. There seems to be no way to effect all from the Windows core, and each one (or at least only Putty who is an independent program) should be juxtaposed differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can position a PuTTY terminal windows using the `t` [ANSI code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

```
printf '\033[3;<x>;<y>t'
```

Replace the `<x>` and `<y>` with desired coordinates, like:

```
printf '\033[3;750;0t'
```

---

To set window size use:

```
printf '\033[8;<height>;<width>t'
```

*(The dimensions are in characters, not pixels)*

---

You can combine these two into one command:

```
printf '\033[3;<x>;<y>t\033[8;<height>;<width>t'
```

---

You can put the command to your (remote) startup script.

Or use the PuTTY [*Remote command* box](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-command) (on the *Connection > SSH* page). As that overrides the default command (starting of a shell), you have to add a shell start too, like:

```
printf '\033[3;750;0t' ; /bin/bash
```